# ¿Como obtener los valores correctos en un edit?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

tengo un problema, estoy haciendo un crud para una tabla de trabajos y tengo dos problemas al llamar campos de la BD, en el primer campo poseo un identificador en una columna en la que todos los campos tienen un patrón de una letra y 3 dígitos por ejemplo E400, pero cuando paso esta a mi campo input text, solo recibo el valor 0 y no entiendo porque. Lo chistoso es que si renombro esta variable en `'paramatrizinfoperio.codpar as c'` y obtengo el valor de C, si recibo el valor correcto. Pero ahí me surge el error, de que me faltan parámetros al momento de entrar al edit. El segundo problema me surge al tratar de poner en mi edit un campo Timestamp a mi datetime-local, ya que pongo mi campo pero mi date time local permanece vacío sin la fecha que le asigne, intente convertir la fecha a un string pero no pasa nada. Asi que mi pregunta seria como puedo hacer que mi campo codpar de tipo varchar y mi Fechaen de tipo timestamps entren a mi edit correctamente.

Paso mi controlador:

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $matriz= pamatrizinfoperio::select('pamatrizinfoperio.codpar', 'pamatrizinfoperio.descripcion','pamatrizinfoperio.data','pamatrizinfoperio.cod_patipoenvio','pamatrizinfoperio.cod_paperiodicidad','pamatrizinfoperio.cod_simoap','pamatrizinfoperio.cod_grupoarchivo','pamatrizinfoperio.status','pamatrizinfoperio.read_at','pamatrizinfoperio.codpaarea','pamatrizinfoperio.Fechaen', 'pamatrizinfoperio.codfecha')->where('codfecha','=',$id)->first();
        return view('matriz.edit', compact('matriz'));
        //return $matriz;
    }
       public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $datosusuario= request()->except('_token', 'Agregar', 'editar');
        $registro= pamatrizinfoperio::where('codfecha', '=', $datosusuario['codfecha'])->first(); 
       $registro->codpar= $datosusuario['codpar'];
       $registro->descripcion= $datosusuario['descripcion'];
       $registro->data= 'Sistema de alertas';
       $registro->cod_patipoenvio= $datosusuario['cod_patipoenvio'];
        $registro->cod_paperiodicidad= $datosusuario['cod_paperiodicidad'];
        $registro->cod_simoap= $datosusuario['cod_simoap'];
       $registro->cod_grupoarchivo= $datosusuario['cod_grupoarchivo'];
       $registro->status= $datosusuario['status'];
        $registro->read_at= 0;
        $registro->codpaarea= $datosusuario['codpaarea'];
        $registro->Fechaen= $datosusuario['Fechaen'];
        $registro->save();
       return redirect('/matriz');
       
        
       
    }
```

y mi view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Editar Envio</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                  <form action="{{route('matriz.update', $matriz)}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
 @method('PATCH')
    
    

    <b><label for="codpar">{{'Codpar:'}}</label></b>
</br>
    <input type="text" name="codpar" id="codpar" value= '{{$matriz->codpar}}'>


 </br>
    <b><label for="descripcion">{{'descripcion:'}}</label></b>
</br>
    <textarea type="text" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" > {{$matriz->descripcion}} </textarea> 
</br>
En este campo pondremos el nombre del envio.
</br>
    <b> <label for="cod_patipoenvio">{{'Tipo de envio:'}}</label></b>
    <select name="cod_patipoenvio" id="cod_patipoenvio" class="form-control">
        <option>{{$matriz->cod_patipoenvio}}</option>
        <option >1</option>
        <option >2</option>
        <option >3</option>
        <option >4</option>
        <option >5</option>
        <option >6</option>
    </select>
</br>

<b><label for="cod_paperiodicidad">{{'Periodo de envio:'}}</label></b>
    <select name="cod_paperiodicidad" id="cod_paperiodicidad" class="form-control">
        <option>{{$matriz->cod_paperiodicidad}}</option>
        <option >1</option>
        <option >2</option>
        <option >3</option>
        <option >4</option>
        <option >5</option>
        <option >6</option>
        <option >7</option>
    </select>
</br>
    
    
    
<b><label for="cod_simoap">{{'Simoap:'}}</label></b>
    <select name="cod_simoap" id="cod_simoap" class="form-control">
        <option>{{$matriz->cod_simoap}}</option>
        <option >1</option>
        <option >2</option>
        <option >3</option>
        <option >4</option>
    
    </select>
</br>   

<b><label for="cod_grupoarchivo">{{'Grupo de archivo:'}}</label></b>
    <select name="cod_grupoarchivo" id="cod_grupoarchivo" class="form-control">
        <option>{{$matriz->cod_grupoarchivo}}</option>
        <option >1</option>
        <option >2</option>
        <option >3</option>
        <option >4</option>
        <option >5</option>
        <option >6</option>
        <option >7</option>
        <option >8</option>
        <option >9</option>
        <option >10</option>
        <option >11</option>
        <option >12</option>
        <option >13</option>
        <option >14</option>
        <option >15</option>
        <option >16</option>
        <option >17</option>
        <option >18</option>
        <option >19</option>
        </select>
</br>   

<b><label for="status">{{'Estado:'}}</label></b>
    <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
        <option>{{$matriz->status}}</option>
        <option >0</option>
        <option >1</option>
        
    
    </select>
</br>
Donde: 1.-Activo y 2.- Inactivo.  Esta parte sirve para informar si el envio aun es parte de los envios de la cooperativa o no.
</br>   
<b><label for="codpaarea">{{'Area:'}}</label></b>
    <select name="codpaarea" id="codpaarea" class="form-control">
        <option>{{$matriz->codpaarea}}</option>
        <option >0</option>
        <option >1</option>
        <option >2</option>
        <option >3</option>
        <option >4</option>
        <option >5</option>
        <option >6</option>
        <option >7</option>
        <option >8</option>
        <option >9</option>
        <option >10</option>
        <option >11</option>
        <option >12</option>
        <option >13</option>
        
    
    </select>
</br>

<b><label for="Fechaen">{{'Fecha de la siguiente entrega:'}}</label></b>
</br>
<input type="datetime-local" name="Fechaen" id="Fechaen" value="{{strtotime($matriz->Fechaen)}}">
</br>

<b><label for="codfecha">{{'Id:'}}</label></b>
    </br>
    <input type="text" name="codfecha" value='{{$matriz->codfecha}}' readonly>
</br>   
    <input type="submit" name="Editar">

</form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

El resultado son todas las filas correctas menos estas dos que menciono, el codpar siempre me da 0 y el Fechaen no se rellena en el datetimelocal. Espero puedan ayudarme se los agradec.

Comment: En las vistas de editar, ya intentaste agregar en value el método old()? Por ejemplo:

`<input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="title"  placeholder="Inserta el titulo"  value="{{ old('title', $exam->title) }}" required>` De esta manera puedes obtener los datos almacenados de tu bd.

Comment: @EdgarGc use <input type="text" name="codpar" id="codpar" value="{{ old('codpar', $matriz->codpar) }}"> pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo solo me da 0 y en el datetime-local igual :(

Comment: Otra preguntas: ¿Como mandas llamar tus datos timestap? si tu creaste el campo, puedes llamarlo desde el controlador con `printType($var->create_at);` En cambio, si creaste una variable con nombre diferente, debes llamarla usando la libreria Carbon. Este hilo te puede ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719972/how-to-get-current-timestamp-from-carbon-in-laravel-5